# How to setup neo4j on EC2 Container Service

Tags: neo4j, amazon-ecs

I am working on to setup dockerized neo4j on EC2 Container Service and failing to do it. Could anyone share some knowledge on how to do it or share resources that helped to setup.

What to configure for mount points and volumes.

I am trying to use t2.micro, does it work with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just set one up yesterday, using the neo4j-docker image.  On your AWS console, locate the AWS Marketplace or navigate to https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace.  Search neo4j, or follow the link below:

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B071P26C9D?qid=1496257991815&sr=0-1&ref_=srh_res_product_title

There you'll see the smallest option is an m3.medium instance.  The t2.micro is really too small to run neo4j.

Just follow the 'Continue' button, review the settings and click Launch.  If you don't like it you can always shut it down, but it's a good way to get started.

Comment: what about enterprise edition? any clues how to go about that? I tried it with the docker datacenter deployment and it was just a grand mess

Comment: also, what is the default password for browser? 'neo4j' isn't working

Comment: same here, creds not working: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48010519/237509