# Neo4j on Amazon Marketplace: Unauthorized with default credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j

I just deployed [Neo4J from Amazon Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B071P26C9D) on Amazon ECS

I can browse to the GUI but the default credentials (neo4j/neo4j) seems to not work.

[image]

The error message reads:

`Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just an extract from the Amazone `Usage Instruction` :

> The default password is your EC2 instance id

So the password is not neo4j ...

Comment: Ah! Where did you copy that from? I now found a similar text here https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-cloud-aws-ec2-ami/ but the Marketplace instruction actually did not come with that info. :)

Comment: Ah I just used Ctrl+F which did not work... after expanding that section it was easier. :)